# imagettftext \\n line break puzzle PART 2

Tags: php, imagettftext

I previously asked why \n in a string was not returning a line break.

This was because the string needed to be in Double Quotes. (Thanks @Juhana !)

Now I am using GET so I can change the text string in the URL

```
$text = $_GET["msg"];
```

And the URL:

```
http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/image.php?msg=Something\nElse
```

Results in outputted text "Something\\nElse"
But what I want is a line break like this:
"Something
Else"

How come the text still has those two backslashes?
Am I wrong to think that because the "msg" is in Double Quotes it should create a line break?

thanks

EDIT full PHP code

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
```

header('Content-Type: image/png');

```
// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 100); //image big enough to display two lines

// Create some colors
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw

//$text = 'Testing\ntesting'; using SINGLE quotes like this results \\n
//$text = "Testing\ntesting"; using DOUBLE quotes like this results in line break

$text = $_GET["msg"];

// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';


// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: did u tryed to use `<br/>` instead of `\n` ??

Comment: Yeah, it just displays <br/> like as if that's what I want the text in the image to say.

Comment: post your full php code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `magic_quotes` are ON on configuration. Thats why adds slash automatic when there special character like `\` (backslash).

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $text = stripslashes($_GET['msg']);
else 
    $text = $_GET['msg'];
```

But if you going to use these in live application, you need more validation for avoid 
security issues. If you sending text with special characters or html tags better use POST method or at least hash code and revese. Your url:

```
http://url.com/image.php?msg=<?php echo base64_encode('your text\n test');>
```

And in image.php

```
$text = isset($_GET['msg']) ? $_GET['msg'] : 'default text';
$text = base64_decode($_GET['msg']);
```

Comment: Very interesting! Now it outputs text with single slash `\n` but the image displays this text in the image rather than creating the line break. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't understand where to put that new code? Do I still need that 'magic quotes' code? It seems to Encode my url, but displays the image encoded, not decoded.

Answer (score 0):

use PHP_EOL like so:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('000.jpg');
$text = "Hello my name is degar007".PHP_EOL."and I am glad to see you";
imagettftext($im, 10, 0, 100, 100, 0x000000, 'DejaVuSans.ttf', $text);
imageJpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

cheers !

Answer (score -2):

did u tryed to use `<br/>` instead of `\n` ??

http://php.net/nl2br

where did u output the text ? in html ?

g.r.

Comment: `nl2br` shows html markup `<br/>` in place of `\n`. I want to know how to write the URL so that `\n` will work and not show two slashes `\\n`

Comment: the idea was that u can use nl2b AFTER the GET.
u could also just do a simple preg_replace 
http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php
so u can search for `\\n` and replace it with `\n`.

Comment: <chill> @Ace needs to <chill/> ?

Comment: why should i chill if there is somebody out there who -1 my answer because i want to help people ? and they wonder that my answer is not the one you're looking for because i don't really know what you want to do. my answer actually was a idea to skirt the problem, and get the result by another way...

Comment: I think you should chill because that's just the way the internet works. You're not setting a great example by taking it out on me when I don't even have enough points to up-vote or down-vote any posts as a new user. If you're worried about your reputation, you can't do much worse than this. Take a break, Ace.